# mkdir and subfolders

Tags: php

Hi i'm not able to test this on the server, but if folder date(Y) does not exist, is this coding write for it to be created. or do I have to do mkdir("/o_rec/" . date(Y) by itself first? Will supporting subfolders all be created if not present

```
if(!is_dir("/o_rec/" . date(Y) . "/" . date(m) . "/" . $id)) {
     mkdir("/o_rec/" . date(Y) . "/" . date(m) . "/" . $id);
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> bool mkdir  ( string $pathname  [, int $mode = 0777  [, bool $recursive = false  [, resource $context  ]]] )

you would need to set recursive to true

Answer (score 3):

You should use set the "recursive" flag on you mkdir call to have it make the entire path you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Be advised that a google search makes it looks like there may be an existing bug, depending on your php version.