# Creating a directory using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a directory with that will create a folder for each month. I would like my directory to be setup like this. Root\subfolder\month . Inside the month folder will be a daily report that will get generated. The problem that I have when i code this is i receive a syntax error saying that there is an uexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR). The code that i have for this looks like this.

```
$month = date('M');
file('Driver Check In\Void\'.$month. '\Void_'.date('m-d-y').".csv");
```

I also have code that will create the month folder if it does not exist.

How can I resolve this issue?

Full Code

```
if(isset($_POST['Void']))
{
    $month6 = date('M');
    $fp6 = file('Driver Check In\Void\\'.$month6. '\Void_'.date('m-d-y'). '.csv');
    $header6 = array("Date", "Customer", "Location/City", "Driver", "Cases", "Bottles", "Reason", "Comment");
    $dates6 = $_POST['dates6'];
    $customer2 = $_POST['customer2'];
    $location2 = $_POST['location2'];
    $driver6 = $_POST['drivers6'];
    $cases6 = $_POST['cases6'];
    $bottles6 = $_POST['bottles6'];
    $reason2 = $_POST['reason2'];
    $comment2 = $_POST['comment2'];
    $result6 = '';
    $search6 = "Date";
    $line_number6 = false;

    while(list($key6, $line6) = each ($fp6) and !$line_number6)
    {
        $line_number6 = (strpos($line6, $search6) !== FALSE);
    }
    if($line_number6)
    {
        $result6 .=
                    $dates6. " ,". $customer2. " ,". $location2. " ,". $driver6. " ,". $cases6. " ,". $bottles6. " ,". $reason2. " ,". $comment2. "\r\n";
    }
    else
    {
        $result6 .= implode(",", $header6). "\r\n".
                    $dates6. " ,". $customer2. " ,". $location2. " ,". $driver6. " ,". $cases6. " ,". $bottles6. " ,". $reason2. " ,". $comment2. "\r\n";
    }
    if(!is_dir('Driver Check In\Void\\'.$month6))
    {
        mkdir('\Driver Check In\Void\\'.$month6);
    }
    file_put_contents('Driver Check In\Void\\'.$month6. '\Void_'.date('m-d-y'). ".csv", $result6, FILE_APPEND);
    echo "data added6";


}
```

Comment: \ is not a valid path separator in *nix - try / since Windows isn't fussy and will accept either.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Currently i am writing this code on a Windows 7 x64 Pro machine. Later on this will be going onto a CentOs machine

Comment: So something very interesting that i did that works. It seems as if my condition for mkdir is not correct. But i know my mkdir is working because before i tried to code it without creating the month folder, and it would create the folder, but when i code for it to create the month folder, it does not work. The part that I did was I created the Void folder. What I was thinking was if it did not find that exact directory, that the code would create the full directory. Am I wrong to assume that? After i created the Void folder and reran the code, I saw a May folder.

Comment: @bobdon yes that is correct, unless you set the `mkdir` option to recursive. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214011/mkdir-and-subfolders) thread for more! I had assumed that you had already made the "Void" Directory

Comment: @AllenButler Best practices, it is recommended to use the recursive option, or it wouldn't matter? This is the first that i have heard of the recursive option. Then again, i haven't worked much with PHP and am just learning still

Comment: @bobdon I think best practice would be to consider the use case. If `Void/`, for example, is going to be a static folder (meaning that it will always have the same name and never change) then I would manually create it on the system. If you want to create a folder with the date as the name (or in other words a dynamic folder) the best option would be to use the recursive parameter.

Comment: @AllenButler Ok, yea i see what you mean. I really do appreciate all of your help with the answer and the explanation. It has really helped me out alot. I think what I will do is manually create the `Void` folder on the system. I think it will be less complications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for one it looks like you have some syntax problems in your `'` and `"` placements. Its also important to know that `\` is considered an [escape sequence](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) which will escape the strings following the mark. Try doing the following:

```
file('Driver Check In\\Void\\'.$month. '\\Void_'.date('m-d-y').'.csv');
```

Have you also considered the [mkdir](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_mkdir.asp) function?

Comment: Oh, ok, i did not know that about `\` that it was considered the escape sequence. Thank you for that one. I could put my whole code up so that way you can see how i have it implemented. I do have a mkdir function in place, but i only have it implemented if that file path does not exist. Give me about 10-15 minutes and I will have my code posted so you can see.

Comment: Ok, did you try replacing your string with the one I provided? I'm not sure if you are still having the problem or not.

Comment: Yes, I replaced with what you have, and I did not get an error message. After I replaced with what you have, i did however receive an error message for syntax.syntax error, unexpected ''"'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING). But when i take away to single ', the error disappears, but then i get warning messages saying that the directory does not exist.

Comment: Yes I edited my answer above about 30 minutes ago removing those extra quotes, I was mistaken about them previously. I would have to see your function to determine why the folder is not being created. One problem that you may have is folder permissions. For example `www-data` is typically the user apache uses on Linux systems, but if `root` owns the folder you want to create a directory in, you will get an error.

Comment: I just updated my post with my code that I am using. I receive 4 warning messages. The first one is file(Driver Check In\Void\May\Void_05-16-16.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. The second one is Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in. The 3rd message mkdir(): No such file or directory. And the 4th message  file_put_contentsDriver Check In\Void\May\Void_05-16-16.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. I just have to look through and see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape your backslashes so them do not consume your quotes.
i would suggest using php constant **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** (listed in here: http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) instead of backslashes..

> 'Driver Check In\Void\'.$month. '\Void_'.date('m-d-y').".csv"

backslash after Void\ consumes the quote and interpret it as part of string, not closing char of the string.